# BNC cameras over CAT5 to powerline adapters then to DVR?

Tags: power-line-communication, balun

My apologies if this has been asked before.

I have four BNC cameras connected to video baluns then connected to CAT5. Each CAT5 cable from the cameras meet in a junction box and then the video signals are sent on to the DVR via another CAT5 cable run and more baluns.  This works perfectly.

However, the CAT5 run to the DVR is temporary because a permanent, neat and tidy run would be very difficult to achieve, so, my question is, instead of a CAT5 cable run from the junction box to the DVR could I use powerline adapters instead?

CAMERAS > VIDEO BALUNS > CAT5 > VIDEO WIRES (8) to RJ45 > POWERLINE ADAPTER 1

POWERLINE ADAPTER 2 > CAT5 > VIDEO BALUNS (4) > DVR

I hope I've explained everything OK.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do will not work.  Here's why:

1) Your cameras are analog.  We know this because you mention BNC connectors and baluns.

2) Using CAT-5 cable for analog signals works quite well, provided you are able to convert the unbalanced signal from the BNC output of the camera to drive the twisted (balanced) pair in the CAT-5 cable.  Your baluns perform this very important function.

3) The Powerline Adapters work with standard Ethernet signals.  These are packet-based, fully digital signals.  The Powerline Adapter simply will not understand the analog signal from the camera.  Similarly, the DVR will not understand the digital signal coming out of the Powerline Adapter.

If you absolutely must Powerline Adapters to get the signals from the cameras to the DVR, you may be forced to replace the entire camera and DVR system with a modern IP-based system.

A modern IP-based camera and DVR system uses standard Ethernet signals that are compatible with your Powerline Adapter.

Comment: Regarding 1) - Modern cameras use BNC still for digital signaling. The standard is called SDI, HD-SDI etc. Cheap units that send this data over ethernet cables do exist, but are known to be somewhat sketchy, and they definitely don't do ethernet packets unless you're buying high-quality units. So while the signals are digital, I agree that his cheap "baluns" won't work with a powerline injector.

Comment: Thank you Dwayne Reid.